# OpenMetadata set custom HTTP headers in web application

Tags: http, metadata, documentation, response-headers, data-ingestion

I am working on the [`OpenMetadata`](https://github.com/open-metadata/OpenMetadata) this moment. Seems like `backend` of the `web application` is written in `Java`. I am interested in, if I can set custom `HTTP` headers from `UI` ? Or it requires to change the source code ?

Any idea ?

I want to achieve this goal from `UI` without change the code, so I carefully find website and I do not find anything useful. Also, I read documentation but no luck.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve by setting custom HTTP headers from the UI. Is it perhaps something related to the search capabilities?  ingestion? please clarify. There are no official way to change the headers afaik but maybe what you want is something different.

Comment: I thought, I would have issues during iframing `OpenMetadata` in my application, but fortunately I wouldn't. Thanks for your attention, I am going to close this ticket.